# What SSH server software for Windows support direct screen access applications?

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, remote, console

SSH for Windows does not support applications that implements direct drawing to the terminal screen buffer (like [FAR Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAR_Manager) I mostly interested in using with SSH). What other SSH servers supports such applications?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a remote desktop solution over SSH, such as UltraVNC?

You can run UltraVNC, and only allow connections from localhost.

Then, using any SSH server software which supports port forwarding, you can connect, and subsequently establish a local port forward. Then, from your seat, connect to the VNC server at "localhost".

It's outside of the box posed by your question, but allows interactivity. Computers at my school in the lab run a VNC server, and I assume this is so that admins can run installers and the like, and not worry about the complicated "rules" of XP for when an application can or cannot access the display, because now, all of them are being launched from the desktop anyway! Just remotely kicked off.